# PHP Databases PDO connections

Tags: php, database, pdo

Hey guys im having a little trouble with the PDO in php as the error it is returning is an undefined index. The code for the function and query and return of result is this:

```
function getUserDetails($user) {
   $db = connect();
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT name,addr AS address,team
FROM TreasureHunt.Player LEFT OUTER JOIN TreasureHunt.MemberOf ON (name=player) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TreasureHunt.PlayerStats USING (player)
WHERE name=:user');

    $stmt->bindValue(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $stmt->closeCursor();

} catch (PDOException $e) { 
    print "Error : " . $e->getMessage(); 
    die();
}
return $results;  
}
```

However when running the code for the index page i get an error that says Notice: Undefined index: name

The Code for the index is this:

```
try {
$details = getUserDetails($_SESSION['player']);
echo '<h2>Name</h2> ',$details['name'];
echo '<h2>Address</h2>',$details['address'];
echo '<h2>Current team</h2>',$details['team'];
echo '<h2>Hunts played</h2> ',$details['nhunts'];
echo '<h2>Badges</h2>';
foreach($details['badges'] as $badge) {
    echo '<span class="badge" title="',$badge['desc'],'">',$badge['name'],'</span><br />';
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Cannot get user details';
}
```

my question is why is it throwing a notice and how do i go around this problem?

Comment: what does `$db = connect();` do? How do you connect with db? What is the content of the error? You put too less details

Comment: Check what you getting using `var_dump($details);`. **Note:** In echo statement concat with `.`(dot) & not by `,`

Comment: Notice can be thrown because there are no proper results and in loop you use `$details['badges']` etc. which may not be assigned. As @Rikesh suggest use var_dump or print_r($details) and show the results.

Comment: @Rikesh `,` in an `echo` statement is preferable, it makes you pass several parameters to `echo` which get echoed out in order. That's more efficient than concatenating strings and then `echo` them out.

Comment: @deceze - I never know that. Thanks :)

Comment: db connect is defined earlier on dw about that

Answer (score 2):

`fetchAll` returns *all* results (potentially multiple rows) in a *multidimensional array*:

```
array(
    0 => array(/* first row */),
    1 => array(/* second row */),
    ...
)
```

That's why the array doesn't have a direct index `'name'`, it needs to be `[0]['name']`.
Or you shouldn't `fetchAll`, just `fetch`.