# Can list an array from database but can't list any specific column of it

Tags: php, mysql

So.. I am trying to get some data out of my database.

```
function my_posts(PDO $dbh, $username) {
global $dbh;
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT      *
    FROM        users u
    WHERE       u.user_username = :username
");

$stmt->bindParam(":username", $username);
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
my_posts($dbh, $username);
$my_posts = my_posts($dbh, $username);

var_dump($my_posts);
var_dump($my_posts['restaurant']);
```

When I > `var_dump($my_posts);` I can see everything in my database.
But when I am trying to get a specific column, the result is null > `var_dump($my_posts['restaurant']);`

[image: var dump]

How come?

array(1) { [0]=> array(18) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_username"]=> string(5) "admin" ["restaurant"]=> string(21) "zzNabilss Steakhousez" ["logotype"]=> string(91) "http://tipsafilm.se/portfolio-n/projects2013/dinmeny/library/img/restaurants/grillhouse.png" ["category"]=> string(9) "Pizzerior" ["phone"]=> string(11) "0520-213328" ["address"]=> string(20) "LantmannavÃ¤gen, 137" ["postal"]=> string(5) "46161" ["city"]=> string(12) "TrollhÃ¤ttan" ["url"]=> string(16) "http://nworks.nu" ["opentimes"]=> string(87) "MÃ¥n-Tors 11.00-21.30, Fre 11.00-22.30, LÃ¶r 12.00-22.30, SÃ¶nd och helgdag 12.00-21.30" ["pickup"]=> string(1) "1" ["todays"]=> string(1) "0" ["delivery"]=> string(1) "1" ["catering"]=> string(1) "1" ["hidden"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_created"]=> string(19) "2013-05-25 00:00:00" } }

Comment: paste your var-dump($my_posts)

Comment: @chandresh_cool pasted it

Comment: No @deceze it's not a duplicate

Comment: `var_dump($my_posts[0]['restaurant']);`

Comment: Post it as text - the font is almost invisible on the image

Comment: @Nabil It most certainly is. Read [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16646556/476), it applies.

Comment: @u_mulder why do I have to use the 0? :) It worked btw

Comment: @Nabil Ghulam of course it works. Because `$my_posts` is array of arrays.

Comment: @deceze noone forced you to help me. If you don't want to help me out then just leave.

Comment: @chandresh_cool did it now.

Comment: Uhm, I took the time to link you to an answer that applies to your problem. I *am* helping you while using the Stackoverflow duplicate system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your results are an array of arrays; the first array is for the rows, the second for the columns.  So to get the first row you use `$my_posts[0]` and to get the restaurant column of the first row `$my_posts[0]['restaurant']`.